# Trying to call jquery from an external js file in ionic 5

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic-framework

all I'm currently working on an ionic app, with angular so l want to call my js function on document ready in the js file but l seems to get an error.

my watch.page.html

```
<ion-content>

<div class="videoContainer" *ngFor="let video of video">
  <div class="videoControls upNext" style="display: none">
   <div class="buttons">
    <button onclick="restartVideo()">
      Rewatch
    </button>
    <button [routerLink]="['/quiz', 1, videoid]">Attempt Quiz</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <video src="https://sgcholdings.co.za/Backend{{ video.video }}" controls></video>
</div>

</ion-content>
```

my js file

```
function goBack(){
 window.history.back();
}

function startHideTimer(){
  var timeout = null;

  $(document).on("mousemove", function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  $(".watchNav").fadeIn();

  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $(".watchNav").fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
  })
}

function restartVideo() {
  $("video")[0].currentTime = 0;
  $("video")[0].play();
  $(".upNext").fadeOut();
}

function showUpNext(){
  $(".upNext").fadeIn();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  // we call the function
 startHideTimer();

});
```

in my index.html l use

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

the error l get is below

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at script.js:28
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`npm install jquery --save`

In angular.json under scripts array add `["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]`

and use in .ts file

import * as $ from 'jquery';

Or

declare var $: any;

Answer (score 0):

so instead of the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // we call the function
  startHideTimer();

});
```

l added

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   startHideTimer();
});
```

and my code works perfectly fine thanks, Ravi